# Why safari is blocking a html change with javascript when location change

Tags: javascript, safari, location

```
$('#bookButton').click(function(){
    $('#bookButton').addClass("hide");
    (location).attr('href',URLTOGO);
)};
```

This code is working as expected in chrome but in safari I can see the class hide added to the html code via safari debugger but the button still visible. If a try to do another type of change in the html code I can see the change in the html code but is not rended visually.

On the other hand the redirection to URLTOGO is working as expected but the button is not hidden. Also if I change the "$('#bookButton').addClass("hide");" command by an alert, the alert works.

Why is happening that ? thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried with `.hide()` ? http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: I think that the css doesn't mutter because if I delete "(location).attr('href',URLTOGO");" command the button is hidden.

Comment: Is it working on IE?

Comment: can you add `$(document).ready` in the beginning of your code?

Comment: Is happening the same

Answer (score 0):

I'd hazard a guess it might be the extra double quotes at the end of URLTOGO?

Failing that, how are the location and URLTOGO elements being called/filled, have you tried outputting the values before setting them as an attribute?

Also, have you tried setting the attr first before changing the class of the bookbutton?

Comment: If it is a guess, put it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I would if it'd let me. Only recently joined so I've got to work on the rep before I can comment on the question directly.

Comment: The code in an example. If I change the (location).attr('href',URLTOGO); for a submit of the form the same is happening. The problems start if I try to change the html code in the same action to change the URL to go.

Comment: Right then, in that case have to made sure that the hide class is capitalized and spelt correctly? And as @callback mentioned tried the jQuery specific command of `.hide()`? So that your code would be `$('#bookButton').hide();`

Comment: $('#bookButton').addClass("hide"); is only an example, any change at dom is done but not  rended visually.